# Make text Align in this Div

Tags: css, html, css-float

Please visit this page : http://www.zomghentai.com/blackmail-episode-3-sub/

Notice the title "Blackmail Episode 3" in the black bar above the video, it is not aligned center.

This is due to the Cinema button on the right side.

How can I make the text align in the center of the box....but still keep it looking proper when there are cases like this: http://www.zomghentai.com/kateikyoushi-no-onee-san-h-no-hensachi-agechaimasu-episode-2-sub/  ...where the text title is very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the single title div to span and wrap around it with a div , and it should work good.
  make the below div float left

```
<div>
<span id="singletitle">
<h1>Kateikyoushi no Onee-san: H no Hensachi Agechaimasu Episode 2</h1>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry that didn't work. The title and Cinema button did not align properly in the same bar

Comment: @virendar , can you try margin-auto also.